$2^{\cos^2(x)}=\sin(x)$
Is there an algebraic way to solve
$$2^{\cos^2(x)}=\sin(x)?$$
I tried
$$\cos^2(x)=\log_{2}(\sin(x))$$
but I have no idea how it could help. Also, since $\cos^{2}(x)=1-\sin^2(x)$, then
$$\frac{2}{2^{\sin^2(x)}}=\sin(x)$$
but it didn't help either.

By inspection, one concludes that $x = \pi/2 + 2k\pi$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ is a collection of solutions.

Are there others?

$0<\cos^2(x)<1\implies 1<2^{\cos^2(x)}<2$ and $-1<\sin(x)<1$. Graphically they are both tangent at  their extrema, so the solution to the equation is at the maximum of $\sin(x)$. Also one can try solving $2^{s^2}s=2$.

@ТymaGaidash I shouldn't use their graphs. Any tips to solve $2^{x^2}x=2$?

Notice that $2^{\sin^{2}(x)}\in[1,2]$. Since $\sin(x)\in[-1,1]$, the only possible solutions correspond to the case where $2^{\sin^{2}(x)} = 2$. This happens iff $\sin(x) = 1$ (because the RHS must be positive)

Notice that $2^{\sin^{2}(x)}\in[1,2]$. Since $\sin(x)\in[-1,1]$, the only possible solutions correspond to the case where $2^{\sin^{2}(x)} = 2$. This happens iff $\sin(x) = 1$ (because the RHS must be positive). In other words, the solutions of the proposed equation are given by $x = \pi/2 + 2k\pi$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

For a purely algebraic approach, I think you were on the right track: $$
\frac{2}{2^{\sin^2(x)}}=\sin(x)\\
\frac{2}{e^{\ln 2 \sin^2(x)}}=\sin(x)\\
\frac{4}{e^{2 \ln 2 \sin^2(x)}}=\sin^2(x)\\
\frac{8 \ln 2}{e^{2 \ln 2 \sin^2(x)}}=2 \ln 2 \sin^2(x)\\
u=2 \ln 2 \sin^2(x)\\
8 \ln 2=u e^u
$$
This can be solved with the W function: $$
u=W_0(8 \ln 2)\\
\sin(x)=\sqrt{\frac{W_0(8 \ln 2)}{2 \ln 2 }}
$$
It turns out (found it on Wikipedia under "special values") that $W_0(x^{x+1}\ln x)=x \ln x$ for $x>0$. You can verify that quickly from the definition of the Lambert function.
This, in turn, gives $\sin(x)=1$
Note we took the positive root only because in the original equation, it is obvious that $\sin(x)>0$.

Well, since $\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x=1,$ then $$2^{\cos^2 x}=\frac{2}{2^{\sin^2 x}},$$ then your equation is equivalent to $$2=2^{\sin^2 x}\sin x.$$ Now, consider $2=2^{y^2}y.$ What can you conclude about the values that the right hand side can take as $y$ varies (such as by using some calculus)? For what values of $y$ (if any) can the right hand side be equal to the left hand side? What does that let you conclude about solutions to the original equation?
